# find all possible rotation of a given string using python

Tags: python

Given string is "abc" then it should print out "abc", "bca", "cba"

My approach: find length of the given string and rotate them till length

```
def possible_rotation():
    a = "abc"
    b = len(a)
    for i in range (b-1):
        c = a[:i] + a[i:]
        print c
```

Above code simply prints abc, abc. Any idea what am I missing here?

Comment: `range(3)` => [0,1,2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def possible_rotation():
    a = "abc"
    b = len(a)
    for i in range (b):
        c = a[i:]+a[:i]
        print c


possible_rotation()
```

Output:

`abc
bca
cab`

You have 2 issues.The range issue and the rotation logic.it should be `a[i:]+a[:i]` not the other way round.For range `range(b-1) should be range(b)`

Answer (score 2):

You have two errors:

- `range(b-1)` should be `range(b)`;
- `a[:i] + a[i:]` should be `a[i:] + a[:i]`.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did. I used a `deque`, A class in collections and then used the rotate function like this

```
from collections import deque

string = 'abc'

for i in range(len(string)):
    c = deque(string)
    c.rotate(i)
    print ''.join(list(c))
```

And gives me this output.

```
abc
cab
bca
```

What it does. It creates a `deque` object, A double ended queue object, which has a method rotate, rotate takes the number of steps to rotate and returns the objects shifted to the right with the number of steps kinda like `rshift` in binary operations. Through the loops it shifts ad produces a deque object that I convert to list and finally to a string.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(b):
   print(a[i:] + a[:i])

0 - [a,b,c] + []
1 - [b,c]   + [a]
2 - [c ]    + [a,b]
```

swap the lists

Answer (score -1):

Two things:

Firstly, as already pointed out in the comments, you should iterate over `range(b)` instead of `range(b-1)`. In general, `range(b)` is equal to `[0, 1, ..., b-1]`, so in your example that would be `[0, 1, 2]`.

Secondly, you switched around the two terms, it should be: `a[i:] + a[:i]`.

Answer (score -1):

No need to do (b-1),You simply do it by:

```
def possible_rotation():
    a = "abc"
    for i in range(0,len(a)):
         strng = a[i:]+a[:i]
         print strng
possible_rotation()
```

`

Answer (score -1):

This looks to be homework, but here's a solution using the built-in [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

```
from collections import deque

def possible_rotations(string):
    rotated = deque(string)
    joined = None
    while joined != string:
        rotated.rotate(1)
        joined = ''.join(x for x in rotated)
        print(joined)
```

Test it out:

```
>>> print(possible_rotations('abc'))
cab
bca
abc
```